# Ros can't find package

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am working with ros hydro ubuntu 12.4.In my catkin-workspace i have my kinect packge ( open cv & kinect line follower), ls gives me the list of file in catkin_ws , i can build catkin successfully.But , when try to run the node I get this message :[rospack] Error: stack/package kinect not found witch is the same with rospack find kinect.what can i do??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190317/ros-can%27t-find-package/) by [ameni mighri](https://answers.ros.org/users/19760/ameni-mighri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-08-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you `source` the `devel/setup.bash` file?

```
$ cd <path-to-catkin_ws>
$ source devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) with karma: 385 on 2014-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to source the ROS environment parameters

```
echo "source <path_to_workspace>/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Close the current terminal and run a new one. You should see the node in the list. If you don't want to close the current terminal, do this:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Note: Pimentel answer is also correct, but you have to do it everytime you open a new terminal. If you added the source command to the bashrc, it will be loaded automatically.

---

Originally posted by [emacsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3662/emacsd/) with karma: 194 on 2014-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1